# Error Creating Shopify Webhook through the API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify, webhooks

I am trying to create a Webhook through the API. 
When the Customer installs the app (Controller):

```
def init_webhooks
  topics = ["products/create", "products/update", "products/delete"]
  topics.each do |topic|
    webhook = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(format: "json", topic: topic, address: "http://#{@current_host}/webhooks/#{topic}")
    raise "Webhook invalid: (#{topic}) #{webhook.errors}" unless webhook.valid?
  end
end
```

Here is the error from the log:

```
RuntimeError (Webhook invalid: (products/create) #<ActiveResource::Errors:0x00000003bd7358>):
```

**EDIT:**
I have even tried just creating one webhook without the block code like so:

```
webhook = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create topic: "products/create", address: "http://myapp.com/webhooks/products/create", format: "json"
```

But I get the same thing.

From my Routes file:

```
  match 'webhooks/products/create' => 'webhook#product_new'
  match 'webhooks/products/update' => 'webhook#product_updated'
  match 'webhooks/products/delete' => 'webhook#product_deleted'
```

I know that the authorization and shop is in fact installing correctly because if I Comment out the 'Raise' error line, I then proceed to the index page which displays some test orders and test products that I created within the Shopify Admin.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks
b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The params you use (`topic`,`format`,`address`) look good to me, but shouldn't it be `ShopifyAPI::Webhook.new` instead of `create`?

Did you now there is a [shopify console](http://wiki.shopify.com/Shopify_API_Console_Guide) where you can easily test your ruby code?