# Webhook not created but no error either

Tags: php, api, shopify, webhooks

I'm trying to create a webhook through the Shopify API. Everything seems fine, but I can't see the webhook created in the backend.

Also, when using the ID received through the response to the API call, I try fetching the webhook (`/admin/webhooks/{#id}.json`) and I get a 404 not found error.

Here is my PHP code that calls the webhook:

```
$key = '123456';
$data = array('webhook' => array(
    'topic'   => 'orders/create',
    'address' => BASEURL.'/webhook?key='.$key,
    'format'  => 'json'
));
$webhook = $shopify->post('webhooks.json',$data);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($webhook); die();
```

Comment: try to pass the complete url  on the address

Comment: I am passing the full URL. BASEURL is just a constant with the domain name (`http://example.com`). so the url will be `http://example.com/webhook?key=123456`. And i can see the url is right in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that webhooks created through the api are not visible form the backend. Also, they are lost once the app is uninstalled.

Comment: That's true, I can only seems to get them through postman, but I don't see them on the store itself. I find this also happens with the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "webhook": {
    "topic": "orders/create",
    "address": "BASEURL.'/webhook?key='.$key",
    "format": "json"
  }
}
```

also   this  may help you

[Error Creating Shopify Webhook through the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411094/error-creating-shopify-webhook-through-the-api)

Comment: Your data is exactly the same. The problem is not that it's not sent the right way, because i can see in the response that it's created. I just can't see it in the backend.