# Registering a Shopify Webhook via the ShopifyAPI gem

Tags: api, rubygems, shopify, webhooks

This call correctly returns an empty array:

```
hooks = ShopifyAPI::Session.temp(s.myshopify_domain, s.shopify_access_token) do
  ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find :all
end
```

While this call always returns a 403:

```
hook = ShopifyAPI::Session.temp(s.myshopify_domain, s.shopify_access_token) do
  ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(
    format:     'json',
    topic:      'orders/fulfilled',
    address:    "http://www.something.fr/api/webhooks?store_id=#{s.id }&store_check=#{ s.checksum }"
  )
end
```

I've tried pretty much all solutions offered over various websites, each time with a failure.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are embedding in your callback URL a store ID and checksum like that? Shopify gives you the shop in the webhook payload and you do security checks with a Shopify HMAC too. So those parameters of yours are basically moot.

Comment: Good hint, but unrelated. In fact, the Shopify store ID is in the headers of the payload, that's why we missed it in the first place.

Comment: Stores do not have an ID per se. The unique key is always the myshopify_domain value. That is what you always key off of. That was my point. So yes, you are right in using 'HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_DOMAIN' as your ID, but I prefer to call that a name, so ya... there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole code block given in original post is correct.
It was in fact a rights problem, the customer who provided us with the API tokens didn't enable webhook creation rights on the Shopify configuration.

It might seem like nothing, but it is critical that you check that with whoever gave you credentials!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hook = ShopifyAPI::Session.temp(s.myshopify_domain, s.shopify_access_token) do
  ShopifyAPI::Webhook.new(
    format:     'json',
    topic:      'orders/fulfilled',
    address:    "http://www.something.fr/api/webhooks?store_id=#{s.id }&store_check=#{ s.checksum }"
  )
end
```

Possible duplicate: [Error Creating Shopify Webhook through the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411094/error-creating-shopify-webhook-through-the-api)

Comment: For us, using a ShopifyAPI::Webhook.new wouldn't persist the object, and we would still get the 403 after calling save on it. Also, the duplicate you're pointing to is something different, we were getting a 403.

Comment: A 403 error on Shopify corresponds to the app authentication issue. Your credentials are either being passed wrong or not being passed at all.

*As you said it has been fixed.*

Comment: What is weird is the fact that querying webhooks / creating a webhook for app uninstall worked, while creating a orders/fulfilled one always gave a 403. Our customer fixed that, so I guess it was something related to the rights he allowed to have.

Comment: Shopify APIs can be given permissions to either POST &/ PUT &/ DELETE &/ GET as required. "Scopes" in their terms. It could, maybe, be related to that. No 100% sure though as I have not worked with scopes.